# How to get image upload date from another website

Tags: php, image

I need to know the image upload date from a jpg file on another website. The image has no EXIF information (everything empty). 
How can it be done? It's not my own server so I can't just use FTP.

Comment: Impossible to know when it was uploaded based on the image alone, but you could check the [filemtime](http://php.net/filemtime). Read the comments for checking remote files.

Comment: Can you upload PHP files to this server hosting the images? If so, you can make and poll a script that returns a given image's info. If the server "plays nice" it might return the modified date in a header if you do a HEAD request.

Comment: No, I don't have access to the server hosting the image(s).

Comment: filemtime works, huge thanks @mistermartin!

Answer (score 0):

You can only get what the server sends you, which in this case is the image *data.*  You don't know where it got the image-data from, and you don't know when it was put there.  ... Unless, by a separate request, the server gives you such information.